# Joining together consecutive date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have versions of the value that need to be combined. Records with other identifiers may also appear in the input table.

How i can do this in MySQL?

Input

```
ID      Prev  Value  StartDate                  Finishdate
1140004 0     0      2019-11-01 00:00:00.000    2019-11-09 23:59:00.000
1140004 0     1      2019-11-10 00:00:00.000    2019-11-14 23:59:00.000
1140004 1     1      2019-11-15 00:00:00.000    2019-11-30 23:59:00.000
```

Expected

```
ID      Prev  Value  StartDate                  FinishDate
1140004 0     1      2019-11-10 00:00:00.000    2019-11-30 23:59:00.000
```

Comment: You will have to specify the rules you are applying to amalgamate those rows i.e. why is the result what it is!!

Comment: Why are you combining rows with `prev = 0` and those with `prev = 1`?

Comment: @DmitryReutov Unfortunately here everyone is allowed their own opinion. So go ahead and give the OP an answer :)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have a versioned table with object states.  In addition to the state processed in this example, the object has several more states according to which versions are cut

Comment: @RiggsFolly they are sliced ​​on top of each other and I can’t change the logic of this table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add more details about your expected result as you will need to perform some sort of aggregation/calculation on the columns which are not ID to get to the one row result you are expecting (as this will of course need to be grouped by ID).

Below, for example, for every Id we get the sum of value, the min StartDate and the max FinishDate. What sort of aggregation you do for each column depends on your use case of course so this is just an example.

You can play around with this example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45318f69cc5dee76b509e7c47fe14ca1).

```
select      Id,
            sum(Value) as "Sum Value",
            min(StartDate) as "Min StartDate",
            max(FinishDate) as "Max FinishDate"
from        data
group by    Id
```

Comment: from the resulting Input table I need to collapse object versions.  Such an input is obtained due to the fact that several states of the object are simultaneously versioned in the source table. Low English , sorry.

Comment: @ПетрАнаньев no problem. So what do the "Prev" and "Value" columns mean? 
In your example it looks like you are doing the min(StartDate) and max(FinishDate) where Value = 1?

Comment: Um, there's a giant hole in this solution.

Comment: These are the states of a particular attribute.  see imagine a table with customers.  the client has “identifier”, “name”, “payment status”, “type of client”, “give start”, “end date”, “version identifier”.  We add several records on one client, each new record will have boundary non-overlapping dates

Comment: First record

Id - 1, Name - Petr, Payment State - 0, Type - 0, SD - 01.01.19, FD - 12.31.99, Verid - 1

Comment: Insert second 

Id - 1, Name - Petr, Payment State - 1, Type - 0, SD - 01.06.19, FD - 12.31.99, Verid - 2

Comment: Result 

Id - 1, Name - Petr, Payment State - 0, Type - 0, SD - 01.01.19, FD - 05.01.19, Verid - 1

Id - 1, Name - Petr, Payment State - 1, Type - 0, SD - 01.06.19, FD - 12.31.99, Verid - 2